# Which index type is best suited for exact-match against a list of values?

Tags: postgresql, index

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.foos (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    bar_string character varying
);
```

I want to do this query:

```
SELECT id from foos where bar_string in ('one', 'two', 'three')
```

The size of the list will be something like 5-100.

If I know I'll only ever be doing this query, what's the best index to put on bar_string? I've read that Hash indexes are better than btree for exact matches, is this the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** `BTREE` looks like it is a bit more efficient than `HASH`. You should read and adapt this test to your situation

## Benchmark

I tried the two solutions for a geohash id column. Here is the script I used:

```rb
require 'set'

def random_geohash(precision)
  letters = %w(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 b c d e f g h j k m n p q r s t u v w x y z)

  letters.sample(precision).join('')
end

geohashes = Set.new

loop do
  geohashes << random_geohash(9)
  break if geohashes.length == 50_000
end


sample = geohashes.to_a.sample(1_000).map { |h| "'%s'" % h }.join(", ")

IO.write("perfs.init.sql", <<~SQL)
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "tests";

  CREATE TABLE "tests" (
  "id_btree" text NOT NULL,
  "id_hash" text NOT NULL
  );

  CREATE INDEX "index_id_btree" ON tests USING btree (id_btree);
  CREATE INDEX "index_id_hash" ON tests USING hash (id_hash);

  INSERT INTO tests (id_btree, id_hash) VALUES #{geohashes.map { |h| "('%s', '%s')" % [h,h] }.join(", ")};
  VACUUM ANALYZE;
SQL

IO.write("perfs.btree.sql", <<~SQL)
  EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)
  SELECT * FROM tests WHERE id_btree IN (#{sample});
SQL

IO.write("perfs.hash.sql", <<~SQL)
  EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)
  SELECT * FROM tests WHERE id_hash IN (#{sample});
SQL

IO.write("perfs.end.sql", <<~SQL)
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "tests";
SQL


`psql --user=john_doe -qAt -f perfs.init.sql my_db`
`psql --user=john_doe -qAt -f perfs.btree.sql my_db > perfs.btree.json`
`psql --user=john_doe -qAt -f perfs.hash.sql my_db > perfs.hash.json`
`psql --user=john_doe -qAt -f perfs.end.sql my_db`
```

This will give you two explain analyze (`perfs.<index>.json`) that you can now read. I suggest using [Pev](http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/new) for a comfortable lecture. Here are the text results for PG11 on my mac:

BTREE

```
Index Scan using index_id_btree on public.tests  (cost=0.29..2611.50 rows=1000 width=20) (actual time=0.988..4.347 rows=1000 loops=1)
  Output: id_btree, id_hash
  Index Cond: (tests.id_btree = ANY ('{e6g8nf3kv,...,3r9n5udye}'::text[]))
  Buffers: shared hit=3014
Planning Time: 1.475 ms
Execution Time: 4.424 ms
```

HASH

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.tests  (cost=1179.75..2758.75 rows=1000 width=20) (actual time=1.784..15.275 rows=1000 loops=1)
  Output: id_btree, id_hash
  Recheck Cond: (tests.id_hash = ANY ('{e6g8nf3kv,...,3r9n5udye}'::text[]))
  Heap Blocks: exact=304
  Buffers: shared hit=1463
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_id_hash  (cost=0.00..1179.50 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=1.714..1.714 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (tests.id_hash = ANY ('{e6g8nf3kv,...,3r9n5udye}'::text[]))
        Buffers: shared hit=1159
Planning Time: 1.495 ms
Execution Time: 15.446 ms
```

Comment: I can not confirm this. For a table with 10 million rows and 1000 elements in the IN list, the hash index is about as fast as the btree index. [plan for hash index on text column](https://explain.depesz.com/s/jNU) [plan for btree on text column](https://explain.depesz.com/s/CrT). When using bigint, the btree index is slightly faster indeed, but it's still a bitmap index scan with the hash index [plan with btree bigint](https://explain.depesz.com/s/YzAN) [plan with hash bigint](https://explain.depesz.com/s/Zf8o)

Comment: Can you add your plans (generated with **`format text`** to make them readable for humans)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name – I added plans. With `IN` and for a `text` field (as in my benchmark) I ended up having a SecScan ignoring completely the HASH index. So in my case, it seems like BTREE is way more efficient.

Comment: Did you run an `analyze` or `vacuum analyze` after populating the table? The estimates are quite wrong in your plans. Are those IDs unique or do you have duplicates?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name – ids are unique, as ruby code points out! Although I did not run either of the commands you point out since I really don't know about these. I'll try and update if the result is different.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name – OK `VACUUM ANALYZE` is a complete game changer, thank you for pointing that out. As you'll see I've updated my answer, encouraging future readers to use this benchmark as a base for their benchmarks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes you are right, For a table with 10 million rows and 1000 elements in the IN list, the hash index is about as fast as the btree index.

Answer (score -1):

**Hash Index:**

> Hash indexes are used only for equality comparisons that use the = or <=> operators. They are not used for comparison operators such as "<" that find a range of values. 
>   The optimizer cannot use a hash index to speed up ORDER BY operations. 
>   Hash indexes can only handle simple equality comparisons. The query planner will consider using a hash index whenever an indexed column is involved in a comparison using the = operator. Only whole keys can be used to search for a row.

**B-tree index:**

> With a B-tree index, any leftmost prefix of the key can be used to find rows.
>   A B-tree index can be used for column comparisons in expressions that use the =, >, >=, <, <=, or BETWEEN operators. The index also can be used for LIKE comparisons if the argument to LIKE is a constant string that does not start with a wildcard character.
>   Constructs equivalent to combinations of these operators, such as BETWEEN and IN, can also be implemented with a B-tree index search. Also, an IS NULL or IS NOT NULL condition on an index column can be used with a B-tree index.

**So, Hash Index are faster for exact matches i.e, =. But can only handle simple equality comparisons cannot use to speed up ORDER BY operations.**

**As you are using `IN` in your query, you should use B-tree index.**

Comment: `As you are using IN in your query, you should use B-tree index.`. Why? Maybe I'm wrong, but it's my understanding that an `IN` clause gets reduced to `= x1 OR = x2 OR = x3...`? Which is the very case for a hash index? Open to correction!

Comment: @Vérace: actually `IN (1,2,3)` is transformed to `= any(array[1,2,3])` - but I do agree both indexes should be usable with an IN condition.

Comment: Is the `array[1, 2, 3]` PostgreSQL specific? Maybe the OP should be  testing?

Comment: That’s both wrong, IN is an equality operation so it is also suited for hash index, however there is no guarantee that a hash index is faster, its just smaller (and only starting with PostgreSQL 10 it might be faster)